# How to change the elements of navbar of User Change Page in Django Admin with Custom User model?

Tags: django

Below is the picture of a User Change Page of Django Admin in which the navbar of the page is marked with red color.

[image]

The name of the app under which the Custom User Model is defined is : **Users**

And the name of the Custom User model is : **Custom User**

So the question is how to change all 4 elements (i.e. Home,Users,Custom users,custom user) of the navbar of the User Change Page of Django admin??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as we can see there are total 4 elements in the navbar of the User Change page of Django Admin :

1.Home

2.Users

3.Custom users

4.custom user

We will change all of these one by one, but first add few lines in the `admin.py` file of the **Users** app (The app under which the the custom user model is defined),which are as follows :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    change_form_template = 'change_form.html'

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

**Explanation for the above code :** First, we have imported important classes among which `UserAdmin` is imported so that it can be used as the base class to define the class `CustomUserAdmin`.Then we have defined the class `CustomUserAdmin`.Later we have registered the class `CustomUserAdmin` to the admin home page.

After this create a folder under the **Users** app (The app under which the the custom user model is defined) by name : **templates**

Now under the **templates** folder create a html file by name : **change_form.html**

In the **change_form.html** file paste the following code :

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls static admin_modify %}

{% block breadcrumbs %}

<div class="breadcrumbs">


<!-- Element 1 --> 
<a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{% trans 'Home' %}</a>
<!-- Element 1 ends --> 


<!-- Element 2 --> 
&rsaquo; <a href="{% url 'admin:app_list' app_label=opts.app_label %}">{{ opts.app_config.verbose_name }}</a>
<!-- Element 2 ends --> 


<!-- Element 3 --> 
&rsaquo; {% if has_view_permission %}
<a href="{% url opts|admin_urlname:'changelist' %}">
{{ opts.verbose_name_plural|capfirst }}</a>{% else %}{{ opts.verbose_name_plural|capfirst }}
{% endif %}
<!-- Element 3 ends --> 


<!-- Element 4 --> 
&rsaquo;
    {% blocktrans with name=opts.verbose_name %}
     {{ name }}
    {% endblocktrans %}
<!-- Element 4 ends --> 



</div>
{% endblock %}
```

So there are 4 sections in the above code and also we have 4 elements in the navbar of the User Change Page.So one section for one element.

**Changing 1st element (i.e. Home)**

For this, you have to go to the section `<!-- Element 1 -->` of the file **change_form.html** in the **templates** folder of the **Users** app (The app under which the the custom user model is defined).

After that replace the string `'Home'` with the name you want to give to the **1st element** of the navbar of the User Change Page .

That's all for this element.

**Changing 2nd element (i.e. Users)**

For this you have to go to the **apps.py** file in **Users** app (The app under which the the custom user model is defined)

And then in the class which would be named like :

**UsersConfig** (i.e. App_NameConfig)

add following line :

`verbose_name = 'Type here the name you want to give to the 2nd element of the navbar of User Change Page'`

**Note:** Make sure you have added the above line in the class only by putting proper space before adding the above line.

That's all for this element.

**Changing 3rd element (i.e. Custom users)**

For this you have to go to the **models.py** file in **Users** app (The app under which the the custom user model is defined)

And there in the **Custom User Model** class you have to add the following code :

```
    class Meta:
        verbose_name="Type here the name you want to give to the 3rd element of the navbar of User Change Page"
```

**Note:** Make sure you have added the above lines in the class only by putting proper space before adding the above lines.

That's all for this element.

**Changing 4th element (i.e. custom user)**

For this, you have to go to the section `<!-- Element 4 -->` of the file **change_form.html** in the **templates** folder of the **Users** app (The app under which the the custom user model is defined).

And there replace **{{ name }}** with the name you want to give to the **4th element** of the navbar of the User Change Page.

*Also if you want to display the name of the user whose details is to be change then you can use :

`{{ original|truncatewords:"18" }}`  in place of **{{ name }}**.*

That's all for this element.

So in this way you can change all the 4 elements of the navbar of the User Change Page of Django Admin with Custom User Model.

I hope it will help you!!